# I am geting "undefined" with this javascript. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been digging around for 4 hours now and I decided to ask, as I can't get my head around this.

I have the following in one page:

support.php:

```
<div id="userID"><?= $dataOwner =></div>
<a class="nav-link" href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="showOpen">Open</a>
<script src="js/tickets.js></script>
```

In the above page (support.php), $dataOwner returns a value correctly.
When clicked, the link must call the "js/tickets.js" script in which I have the following:

tickets.js:

```
$("#showOpen").click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: 'https://[redacted]/load_tickets.php?user='+$('#userID').val(),
            success:function(data) {
                document.getElementById('openTickets').innerHTML = data;
            }
    });
});
```

but the value of #userID is always undefined.
Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no element with `id=userID` in your (provided) html. Did you mean  `$("#customer").text()` ?

Comment: Divs don't have a value. Try `$('#userID').text()`.

Comment: Where is the html code for click event?

Comment: Might be nothing, but you've missed a closing double quote on the script src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, don't use shorthand in php - might cause errors when moving servers at any point.

secondly.. no inline JS!!!

and lastly, you're using url params for a post method.

How I'd do it (and how I'd recommend):

[support]

```
<div id="customer" data-id="<?php echo $dataOwner; ?>">
    <?php echo $dataOwner; ?>
</div>

<a href="#" class="nav-link" id="showOpen">Open</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#showOpen').on('click', function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                data: {user: $('#customer').data('id')},
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                url: '/your/path/to/load_tickets.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#openTickets').html(data)
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

then no need for `tickets.js` (in this case)

this will post the data to the file as `$_POST` (array) where you can use `$_POST` however you want :)

Comment: I am back to clarify what my real issue was. I managed to figure it out last night. Your solution does work, other solutions may work too, but it required the page to be refreshed first. I've seen this behaviour when either an element is not yet loaded when javascript fires, or when a script is loaded more than once. In my case it was none of these and while I could not identify the real issue, I managed to work around it by defining $userID on another page (the first one the user visits when they log in). After doing this, everything started working. But still with your code of course.

Comment: ah to get passed the newly created element - use `$(document).on('event', '.className', function() {//do stuff});` and that will pick it up :) classname can be an id too but glad my answer helped out :)